# Setting myself to null - Java

Tags: java, null, linked-list

I came across the following problem:

Delete a node in the middle of a singly linked list, given only access to that node. (head is not given)
Now there are a lot of solutions and they all do not work when the element to be deleted is the last node.

Why wouldn't this work?

```
public static void removeNode (Node n){
    if(n.next == null){ //n is the last node
        n= null;
        return;
    }
    //handling general case here
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java passes parameters by value, so setting n to null has no effect outside of the method. This means the method essentially does nothing when passed the last node of a list.

Comment: +1 for explaining **why** it doesn't work. You beat me to it by just a hair!

Comment: Why does n.next= null work? Wouldn't that be changing the n local to the method as well?

Comment: The object that `n` points to is shared with the caller. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Answer (score 2):

You need to set null the reference in the previous node, not the variable that references to your last node, something like this:

```
if(n.next == null) {
    prev.next = null;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`n` is local to the method, so changing its value won't affect the list itself. You need to modify the `next` of the previous node, which you do not have access to.